# Is that possible to stream Windows desktop to upnp media player or LCD TV

Tags: windows, media-player, upnp

We may use Windows Media Player to stream media content to UPnP devices or TV.  I wish to to stream the Windows desktop to the UPnP devices or TV.  Is this possible?